# Difference between node.role and master stats in Elasticsearch Cluster Settings?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ES 2.4.0. I am having a cluster that is running by 3 nodes when i given the following command `http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v` i got to see there stats like these

```
host      ip        heap.percent ram.percent  load node.role master name     
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            7          73 -1.00 d         m      Aguja    
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            7          73 -1.00 d         m      Hardwire 
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            3          73 -1.00 d         *      Glitch
```

The node.role and master is done by default as it is given in the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-node.html

In the above stats you can able to see the master eligible node (i.e Glitch) and its role is datanode(d) . Eventhough it is elected master it is performing the responsibilites of both the master and also datanode.

My question is :
1)Since the Glitch is doing both master and data node tasks whether the performance of the node Glitch will be slow? and also is it a good practice in doing so?
2)Can i able to declare the node.role as dedicated master for the Glitch?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this answers your question but [elasticsearch reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-node.html) states:

> By default a node is both a master-eligible node and a data node. This is very convenient for small clusters but, as the cluster grows, it becomes important to consider separating dedicated master-eligible nodes from dedicated data nodes.

You may set nodes as "dedicated master" using the following options in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
node.master: true 
node.data: false
```